# Append reg_multi_sz value

Tags: append, registry, addition

I am trying to append a value to an existing registry value which is a REG_MULTI_SZ entry.  Here is the small batch file...

```
set regpath=HKCU\Software\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0x64\Scheme: Default\Window Positions\Docking Toolbars
set regvalue=Rui files
set regdata=C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5.0\Plug-ins\Deadline7\deadline.rui
reg query "%regpath%" /v "%regvalue%"

reg add "%regpath%" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /v "%regvalue%" /d "%regdata%"
```

The entry I am trying to append to is the string "Rui files"  For arguments sake let's say the values that are tied to "Rui files" are the paths: C:\test1 and C:\test2.  I need to add on the 3rd line the entry that is shown above next to regdata which starts with C:\Program Files, etc.  The reg add command at the bottom is what I am trying to run.  I need to append the C:\Program Files path to the "Rui files" entry which is the C:\test1 and C:\test2 paths.  Is it possible to do without overwriting the existing entries and just adding to them?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are.

```
set regpath=HKCU\Software\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0x64\Scheme: Default\Window Positions\Docking Toolbars
set regvalue=Rui files
set regdata=C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5.0\Plug-ins\Deadline7\deadline.rui

FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=1 delims= " %%i IN ('reg query "%regpath%" /v "%regvalue%"') DO (reg add "%regpath%" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /v "%regvalue%" /d "%%i\0%regdata%")

rem Just use this to append that value
rem Reg.exe util uses \0 to separate REG_MULTI_SZ by default.
rem By Misty At 2015.9.23
rem Tested On Win7 x64 using value "netsvcs" in
rem HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Svchost
```